# How to address "Error running SQL query." error in python

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to upload a table to snowflake and keep running into the "Error running SQL query." error when running the code. Specifically, it is failing at the following line:

```
with snowfox.Cmd() as cmd:
        cmd.execute(staged_query_string)
```

and giving the following error

`ERROR:snowfox.core:Error running SQL query. err: 003112 (55000): 018d1453-0037-dce0-0000-0010f2232e1e: Table "TABLENAME" cannot be modified.  It is within Database "DATABASE" which is in a replication group and is not currently the primary.`

I had the program working and doing what was intended and all of a sudden after a week or so of using it, it stopped working.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: More Information please. What does your SQL Code look like? Select, Update, Insert, Delete? The Error code is realy readable, looks like your database is running on Replikation mode.

Comment: Did the server failover? Maybe the primary became the readonly?

Comment: Yes, it did failover. Sorry, I didn't realize that this had occured

Comment: Does your Snowflake account have Disaster Recovery / Replication?
Is your Snowflake not doing replication to another account on another region?